# How to implement multi pick calendar on React Native Stript Calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

so I have this problem here.
I am trying to implement multi pick calendar on my current code, I've been trying to figure this out while using array, but nothing happen.

Here's my clean code.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import CalendarStrip from "react-native-calendar-strip";

export default function App() {
    const tomorrow = new Date()
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
    const selected = new Date()
    selected.setDate(selected.getDate() + 2)
    const datesBlackList = [
        {
            start: new Date(0),
            end: tomorrow
        }
    ]

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CalendarStrip
        scrollable
        startingDate={new Date()}
        datesBlacklist={datesBlackList}
        style={{ height: 200, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}
        calendarColor={"white"}
        calendarHeaderStyle={{ color: "black" }}
        highlightDateNameStyle={{ color: 'black'}}
        highlightDateNumberStyle={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'green', width: 25, height: 25 }}
        dateNumberStyle={{ color: "black" }}
        dateNameStyle={{ color: "black" }}
        iconContainer={{ flex: 0.1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to mark multiple dates ?

Comment: Yes. So for example, user can choose date 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment, you are trying to have a feature to mark several dates.
This can be done using the prop **markedDates**

The code would be like below

```
export default function App() {
  const tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

  const datesBlackList = [
    {
      start: new Date(0),
      end: tomorrow,
    },
  ];

  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get
        a shareable url.
      </Text>

      <CalendarStrip
        onDateSelected={(date) => {
          const dates = [...markedDates];

          const index = dates.findIndex((x) =>  moment(x.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
       
          if (index > -1) {
            dates.splice(index,1);
          } else {
            dates.push({
              date: date,
              dots: [{ color: 'red'},],
            });
          }
          setMarkedDates(dates);
        }}
        scrollable
        startingDate={new Date()}
        datesBlacklist={datesBlackList}
        style={{ height: 200, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}
        calendarColor={'white'}
        calendarHeaderStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
        highlightDateNameStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
        highlightDateNumberStyle={{
          color: 'white',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
        }}
        dateNumberStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
        dateNameStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
        iconContainer={{ flex: 0.1 }}
        markedDates={markedDates}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The logic is to maintain a array in state and add and remove the date when its clicked.

You can check the snack for this
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/datesample

Comment: Wow, impressive. I've been messing around with array and still can't figure it out. Thanks a lot dude!